# Is there a way to find every single modules which will be needed in script?

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-module

I'd like to use a kinda analyzer which will install/import all the needed modules by the script before I run it on distant machine (which could not have it) ......

any idea ?

**EDIT**

Here's the case :
I'm on my dev machine, I'ved already installed lots of modules of all kind (dhcp, ntfs, remoting, register, etc.)
When I finally got my script (which is a function) to work, I can't be sure of what modules are used....

What I want is to write down, in the 'begin' section, the correct imports before I send my script on remote PCs; to be sure it's gonna run perfectly, you follow ?...

Is there a kinda a third party appplication which can scan my script and give me all needed modules ?

Comment: You should already be aware of what modules are needed by your script and build in checks

Comment: What I am aware of, is that my script run perfectly on the remote PC...thnx for your constructive comment

Comment: You're welcome.  Thank you as well for the excellent question!

Comment: So my point is, when you write scripts/module you should already know in advance what other modules are needed.  You can then mark your script/module with #Requires flags and such.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: I understand your point but, as silly as it could sound to you, if my question wasn't that excellent, it was really pointing out MY needs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this to get help in finding commands used and their source/module names.  It's very unpolished, just trying to give the idea.

```
$scriptblock = {
    Write-Host "Nothing here"
    $files = Get-ChildItem c:\temp
    Get-ADUser someuser
    Test-NetConnection www.google.com
}

# Uncomment following lines and enter the path to your script file
# $scriptFile = "Path\to\some\scriptfile"
# $scriptblock = [scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content -raw -Path $scriptFile))

$ast = $scriptblock.Ast

$commands = $ast.FindAll( { $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.CommandAst] }, $true)
$commandText = foreach ($command in $commands) {
    $command.CommandElements[0].Extent.Text
}

$commandText | 
    Select-Object -Unique | 
    Sort-Object |
    Select-Object @{
        Label      = "CommandName"
        Expression = { $_ } 
    },   
    @{
        Label      = "Source"
        Expression = { 
            (Get-Command $_).Source
        } 
    }
```

Output

```
CommandName        Source
-----------        ------
Get-ADUser         ActiveDirectory
Get-ChildItem      Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Test-NetConnection NetTCPIP
Write-Host         Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
```

Comment: I know it is asked to avoid that kind of comment...but it works !!
Pretty well actually !!!.. You're awesome !

Thnx !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you could for example test if the module exists on that particular machine by trying to import it as follows

```
Try {
   Import-Module dbaclone -ErrorAction stop
   #ErrorAction required as failing to import is not a terminating action
} Catch {
   Write-Verbose -Verbose "Failed to find dbaclone module - installing"
   Install-Module dbaclone -AllowClobber -Force 
   Write-Verbose -Verbose "Installed!"
   Import-Module dbaclone
}
```